# Comprobar si un elemento existe dentro de un Array

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Resulta que estoy haciendo una app que contiene una lista que se lanza desde un `CustomDialog`. Al seleccionar uno ó mas de sus items voy guardando los ID's en un array quedando así `[1, 3, 5, 6]`. Con un botón "Cancelar" se limpia el `ArrayList` y se cierra el diálogo.

```
deleteIds.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    myArrayList.clear();
                    dialogView.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

El problema viene con el otro botón que es el de "Guardar" cuya acción es solamente cerrar el diálogo por ende la lista se queda cargada con los elementos que yo seleccioné. El punto es que al volver a abrir el diálogo y elegir un item que ya había cargado antes la lista se queda de esta forma: `[1, 1, 3, 5, 6]`. Existe alguna forma de dar a entender que ya se ha marcado? Como verifico si ese item que volví a seleccionar ya está cargado en la lista?

Estuve pensando en algo similar a darle un color distinto dentro del `setOnItemClickListener`.

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ADD8E6"));
```

Me han dicho que puedo dejar pintado de un color distinto los que ya tengo seleccionado en la lista pero no se me viene la idea de como hacerlo. Espero puedan ayudarme y gracias de antemano!

Comment: usas el setMultipleChoiceItem y le pasas los Checked ?

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de usar un arrayList puedes usar un conjunto de tipo Set, como un HashSet. Set es una interface que se usa para representar colecciones donde no se puede repetir ningún elemento. HashSet es una clase que hereda de Set.
Puedes instanciar el objeto de esta forma:

```
Set<Integer> iDs = new HashSet<>();
```

Set tiene el método add, el cual devuelve un boolean. Si devuelve true, es que el elemento se pudo añadir; si devuelve false es que el elemento ya existe en el conjunto y no lo puedes añadir.

De esta forma no podrás tener elementos repetidos en tu conjunto de ID's.

Si también quieres que los items que se encuentran en la lista no se puedan volver a seleccionar prueba con

```
item.setEnable(false);
```

recorres tu lista de ID's y todos los que existan los pones a false, o les das una apariencia diferente.

Answer (score -1):

Utilizando java 8 en cualquier Coleccion, para eliminar elementos repetidos:

```
List<Elemento> lista= viejaLista.stream().distinct().collect(Collertos.toList);
```

Si quieres simplemente saber si tiene algun elemento:

```
Boolean existe= viejaLista.stream().anyMatch(elemnto-> elemento.getId()==1);
```

Si regresa un `true` es que dicho elemento existe.
EDIT:
Para comprobar si un elemento existe es el mismo paso para los demas

```
 `Boolean existe= viejaLista.stream().anyMatch(elemento-> //aqui colocas un predicado como este
elemento==objetoAComparar`);
```

Recuerda que hacer esto comparara las referencias de ambos objetos, por eso te sugiero que ajustes el predicado a lo que necesitas encontrar

Comment: *Si quieres simplemente saber si tiene algun elemento: `viejaLista.stream().anyMatch(elemnto-> elemento.getId()==1);`* -> esto no te dice si la lista tiene algún elemento, solo si la lista contiene algún elemento con `id == 1`. Un usuario con poca experiencia en java o con streams podría confundirse facilmente si dices que eso se usa para saber si hay elementos.

Comment: El ejemplo que proporcione es uno generico, no tengo ni idea de que sea el array. pro te invitp a que en vez de criticar posibles soluciones proporciones una.